# How can I show SupportMapFragments in every RecyclerView item?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, supportmapfragment, fragmentmanager

I want to show a small location on every item in a recyclerview using a  SupportMapFragment replacing a framelayout. Only the first item is showing the map fragment, but the location in that fragment is the location of the last item in the recylcerview. I believe it has to do with the fragmentmanager or some IDs being the same. Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [article](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/embedding-custom-views-with-mapview-v2/) about this issue posted on Big Nerd Ranch. The issue they ran into using fragments is that the lifecycle events will not be in sync with the `RecyclerView`, which could lead to huge memory issues. They instead used a `MapView` and tied the lifecycle events to those of `RecyclerView.Adapter`. I suggest following the tutorial in the article.